# Migrating MS SQL Server database to Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, database

I have an issue migrating my database from my PC to Azure. I cannot install the Data Migration Manager. I have already allowed port 1433 in my firewall and I am getting further in the installation process but I am still getting an error message: "verify that you have sufficient privilages".

I cannot run the installer as admin (the option isn't there) and I am not sure if this is the cause of the problem.

Thanks for help!

Matěj Bischof

Comment: What do you mean with the 'Data Migration Manager'? There's a possibility to migrate databases to Azure from SQL Server Management Studio, have you tried that one?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the options you have in this very good piece of documentation:

Azure Database Migration Guide - [Migrate SQL Server to Azure SQL Database](https://datamigration.microsoft.com/scenario/sql-to-azuresqldb)

> Data migration options, details, and supported versions:
>
> **Azure Database Migration Service**
>   Azure DMS supports online (minimal downtime) and offline (one time) migrations at scale to an Azure SQL Database managed instance from SQL Server 2005, SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2008 R2, SQL Server 2012, SQL Server 2014, SQL Server 2016, and SQL Server 2017.
>
> **Data Migration Assistant**
>   Use DMA to detect compatibility issues that can impact database functionality in your target Azure SQL Database managed instance, to recommend performance and reliability improvements, and to move the schema, data, and uncontained objects from your source server to your target server. For information about supported sources and targets, and to download the latest version of DMA, see the Microsoft Download Center.
>
> **Transactional replication**
>   Transactional replication to an Azure SQL Database managed instance is supported for migrations from: SQL Server 2012 (SP2 CU8, SP3, or later), SQL Server 2014 (RTM CU10 or later, or SP1 CU3 or later), SQL Server 2016, SQL Server 2017
>
> **Bulk load**
>   Use bulk load to an Azure SQL Database managed instance for data stored in SQL Server 2005, SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2008 R2, SQL Server 2012, SQL Server 2014, SQL Server 2016, and SQL Server 2017.